# NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated. (DNSControl)

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, gcloud

I am trying to implement dnscontrol to use route 53, but it seems it does not see what I put inside creds.json file when I run any command e.g "dnscontrol get-zones gcloud GCLOUD mydomain.com"

It returns the error:

NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors

---

I did place the credentials inside creds.json in the format below:

{
"r53_main": {
"KeyId": "mywhateverkeyid",
"SecretKey": "mywhateversecretkey"
}
}

My gcloud credentials work fine inside the same creds.json file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to authenticate against Google (Cloud DNS), you will need to use a (Google) Service Account JSON key as described [here](https://stackexchange.github.io/dnscontrol/providers/gcloud).

It appears you may be trying to use Route 53 credentials as described [here](https://stackexchange.github.io/dnscontrol/providers/route53).

#### Example

```sh
PROJECT=[[PROJECT]]
BILLING=[[BILLING]]
DNSNAME=[[DNSNAME]]
ACCOUNT=[[ACCOUNT]]

gcloud projects create ${PROJECT}
gcloud beta billing projects link ${PROJECT} --billing-account=${BILLING}
gcloud services enable dns.googleapis.com --project=${PROJECT}

# Create a test DNS Managed Zone
gcloud dns managed-zones create test \
--description=test \
--dns-name=${DNSNAME} \
--project=${PROJECT}

# Create a Service Account (permitted to use DNS) and Key
gcloud iam service-accounts create ${ACCOUNT} --project=${PROJECT}

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT} \
--member=serviceAccount:${ACCOUNT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
--role=roles/dns.admin

gcloud iam service-accounts keys create ./${ACCOUNT}.json \
--iam-account=${ACCOUNT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
--project=${PROJECT}
```

You will need to then combine the key into a `creds.json`:

```sh
echo "{\"gcloud\":$(cat ./${ACCOUNT}.json)}" > ./creds.json
```

Then:

```sh
./dnscontrol check-creds gcloud GCLOUD
${DNSNAME}

./dnscontrol get-zones gcloud GCLOUD ${DNSNAME}
$ORIGIN ${DNSNAME}.
$TTL 300
@          21600 IN NS    ns-cloud-b1.googledomains.com.
           21600 IN NS    ns-cloud-b2.googledomains.com.
           21600 IN NS    ns-cloud-b3.googledomains.com.
           21600 IN NS    ns-cloud-b4.googledomains.com.
```